# Is there any similar function with MySQL trigger in IBM Netezza?

Tags: triggers, sqoop, netezza

As you can see on the title, I want to know the similar function with MySQL's trigger function. What actually I want to do is importing data from IBM Netezza Databases using sqoop incremental mode. Below is the sqoop scripts what I'm going to use.

```
sqoop job --create dhjob01 -- import --connect jdbc:netezza://10.100.3.236:5480/TEST \
--username admin --password password \
--table testm \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column 'modifiedtime' --last-value '1995-07-18' \ 
--target-dir /user/dhlee/nz_sqoop_test \
-m 1
```

As the official Sqoop documentation says, I can gather data from RDBs with incremental mode by making a sqoop import job and execute it recursively.
 Anyway the point is, I need a function like MySQL trigger so that I can update the modified date whenever tables in Netezza are updated. And if you have any great idea that I can gather the data incrementally, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: You want a column to know the last time a row was updated?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Each row in modifiedtime column should be updated when the 'UPDATE' query executed for that row.

Comment: You'll need to accomplish this by changing your `UPDATE` statements to explicitly set a column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't anything similar to triggers available. I would recommend modifying the relevant `UPDATE` commands to include setting a column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

In Netezza you have something even better: 
- Deleted records is still possible to see http://dwgeek.com/netezza-recover-deleted-rows.html/
- the INSERT- and DELETE-TXID are a rising number (and visible on all records as described above)
- updates are really a delete plus an insert

Can you follow me?

Comment: It means that I can see the rows that I deleted for each table... right? Then how about  the updated rows and inserted rows? I've tested each case on my netezza but I cannot see any row as below. I really need your help.

Comment: The key is to run it before you GROOM the table and run it in the SAME session as the ‘set show_deleted_records = true;’ statement... Aginity creates a new session each time you run a statement (by default) so does many other tools

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y81ge.png)

This is the screen shot that I've got after I inserted and deleted some rows.